# When shrinking site's size, body is not 100% width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

When I lower site's size when inspecting it, the body is not 100% width of the screen.

[image: problem]

When I delete the Bootstrap classes it seems to work as it should.
added a `body{width: 100%}` with no result. I've noticed that deleting 'p-md-4' from classes makes the gap a little smaller.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class=" row align-items-center bg-primary">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-12 mt-md-0 mt-0 p-md-4 ms-md-2 ms-3 p-3">
    test
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you understand what styles are on primary structural classes like `col` and don't add anything that goofs that up. Also make sure you're using a container element outside your row, per Bootstrap's docs. That's critical.

If your goal is to create space around your column content, use padding on the column (which doesn't affect column size or position) or additional, interior elements with margin. Don't move the columns.

Of course you could also modify gutter sizes across the board, which might be better than one-off overrides. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#sass-variables.

Also, list your column size classes in the proper (mobile first) order. This is a convention in the Bootstrap world and makes your markup easier to interpret. It also corresponds to the way the actual CSS media queries are written.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <header class="row align-items-center bg-success">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="m-4 bg-warning">test</div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```